# Android get current song playing and song changed events, like Musixmatch

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications, android-broadcast

What i want to achieve is very similar to what [Musixmatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musixmatch.android.lyrify&hl=en) is doing.

I need to be informed when the music starts playing and when the song is changed.
All this in the service because my app may be closed (even musicmatch does this).

[image]

[image]

In the above case even if Musixmatch app is not running i get a notification when ever i change the song on spotify or any player.

Can anyone pls tell me how to achieve this.
I don't need the code help, just what to know how to achieve it. I'm really confused how Musixmatch is doing it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html is this what you looking for

Comment: Mean, musixmatch detecting all the events from other players also?

Comment: yeah all players, spotify.. google music. @NigamPatro

Comment: Refer this, may be this will be helpful https://developer.musixmatch.com/documentation

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to find if music player is playing.

```
   AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(manager.isMusicActive())
     {
         // Something is being played.
     }
```

then You can get information from music player what song is currently playing.
Paste code below to your onCreate method in your activity class.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();

        // Read action when music player changed current song
        // I just try it with stock music player form android

        // stock music player
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");

        // MIUI music player
        iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");

        // HTC music player
        iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");

        // WinAmp
        iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");

        // MyTouch4G
        iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
    }
```

In your activity class create new BroadcastReceiver mReceiver.

```
 BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

                String action = intent.getAction();
                String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
                Log.d("mIntentReceiver.onReceive ", action + " / " + cmd);
                String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
                String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
                String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
                Log.d("Music", artist + ":" + album + ":" + track);
                 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm familiar with this code. This only helps me find if music is being played and then get track details. But what I'm looking for is an event listener which triggers when the music starts playing and song changes event... are you aware of such ? check the app i mentioned above it gets everything without even laughing the app.

Comment: Write a service class for saving current song and check it with next song.. when the song changes to next song you can use notification..

Comment: u mean i check periodically, say every 5 seconds if the song has changed ? That doesn't sound very professional, there has to be a better way.  @Akhil

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into similar (understanding events and intents, and what's possible without rooting, with automate, tasker, Google assistant routines, adb, and (first:) MacroDroid

I hope you're still looking into this!
This doesn't answer your requirements, but may be useful to note

(re spotify)

metadata change intent is sent when a new track starts playing. It uses the intent action com.spotify.music.metadatachanged, and contains the following intent extras