# How to get the Youtube video info on our application?

Tags: android, youtube, notifications, mediacontroller

I saw on many applications that they can get the info of current playing youtube video's title, duration etc on there application.

See this response

```
title: Desiigner- Panda (OFFICIAL SONG) Prod. By: Menace
album: null
artist: Desiigner LOD
duration: 248000
position: 33154
positionTimestamp: 438260822
source: com.google.android.youtube
playing: true
artworkUri: null
supportedActions: 560
```

May I know how I can get this info on my application ?

Comment: Check the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

Comment: @shiftpsh let me check it

Comment: [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) exists too

Comment: @shiftpsh But these api is for doing the youtube functionalities inside our app.My situation is different. 
I think there is other method without using the api. Please check the response above. It looks like the info gets from media controller . We get the same result when we use NotificationListener class.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389404/android-get-current-song-playing-and-song-changed-events-like-musixmatch

Comment: @ianhanniballake MediaBrowser is failed to connect with Youtube Music

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get data for Youtube Videos or play Youtube Videos on your app etc. you can use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). It's easy to integrate and it's Google's official API for getting video data from youtube. If you want to use the whole [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) you can also look at the documentation. You can look at the Github samples for the [API](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples). Good Luck!

Comment: But my requirement is getting info from youtube app to my application

Comment: Can you please give an application that can get info from youtube app to itself. It would be super helpful, as I could give you information on how the app works.

Comment: Shazam,Musixmatch etc

Comment: I hope it is possible by media controller.But I don't know how to get the result

Comment: You can use, in my opinion, ContentProviders. Have a look here at the documentation and look if you use this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers;

Comment: By the way, if you want to develop an application which searches for music videos and plays them I'll suggest you display a UI where the user searches and you can then use the Youtube API to play it in your app with custom controls.

Comment: @user9998656 Sorry, your answers are not relevant to my questions

Answer (score 0):

They get this information via logcat:

[image]